# RTC + Scheduler using Arduino mini

Tags: arduino, scheduler, real-time-clock

I am using Arduino mini 5V for my project and RTC - Real Time Clock Module DS1307
I would like to wake the board at a certain time and run a function. (Buzzer is connected to D3)

When I use the TimeAlarm alone and manually set the time everything works fine:

```
#include "Time.h"
#include "TimeAlarms.h"

void setup(){
  setTime(22,29,55,12,31,14); // set time to Saturday 8:29:00am Jan 1 2011

  Alarm.alarmRepeat(10,30,0,buzz);  // 10:30am every day
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(16,30,0,buzz);  // 4:30pm every day 
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,30,0,buzz);  // 10:30pm every day 

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  digitalClockDisplay();
  Alarm.delay(1000);
}

void buzz(){
   tone(3, 220, 1000);
}

void digitalClockDisplay(){
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  printDigits(second());
  Serial.println(); 
}

void printDigits(int digits){
  Serial.print(":");
  if(digits < 10)
  Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}
```

---

However when I use RTC the buzzer function wouldn't get called, it still prints the time though

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "TimeAlarms.h"

RTC_Millis rtc;

void setup(){
  rtc.begin(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));

  Alarm.alarmRepeat(10,30,0,buzz);  // 10:30am every day
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(16,30,0,buzz);  // 4:30pm every day 
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,30,0,buzz);  // 10:30pm every day -- modify this to your current time when running the example

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  //printing the current time
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  Serial.print(now.year());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day());
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(now.hour());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second());
  Serial.println();
  Alarm.delay(1000); // wait one second between clock display
}

void buzz(){
  tone(3, 220, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see any references to `buzzer` in the lower snippet...

Comment: I had to edit the example here for privacy reasons. So here I corrected it now. Thank you for mentioning that!

Comment: Can you get the anonymized, reduced version to run?

Comment: above code should be running, vibration motor is connected to pin D3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I found the answer:

First problem was: using RTC_DS1307 instead of RTC_Millis

RTC ds1307 is referring to pin 12C which in Arduino mini they are above A3 and VCC. They require soldering. Once that's done they should be connected to SDA and SCL, using M/F wires

```
SDA -> to the pin above A3
SCL -> to the pin above VCC
```

Then I changed the code to the following:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "TimeAlarms.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
const int output = 3;

uint32_t syncProvider()//function which sets up the RTC as the source of external time{
  return rtc.now().unixtime();
}


void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));//comment this out when the RTC has been set
  setSyncProvider(syncProvider);   // the function to get the time from the RTC


  Alarm.alarmRepeat(10,30,0,buzzer);  // 10:30am every day
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(16,30,0,buzzer);  // 4:30pm every day 
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,30,00,buzzer);  // 10:30pm every day 

  pinMode(output , OUTPUT);//new line
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  //printing the current time
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  Serial.print(now.year());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day());
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(now.hour());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second());
  Serial.println();
  Alarm.delay(1000); // wait one second between clock display
}

void buzzer(){
 //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help noob like me who did tried this code by using copy paste and get error

> named return values are no longer supported Error compiling.

After searching through the net found that the **{** the infamous curly bracket is part of comment so please change the same to

```
uint32_t syncProvider() { //function which sets up the RTC as the source of external time       
       return rtc . now() . unixtime(); 
   }
```